# Tool for finding Domain Names from a list of suggestions

Tags: domain-name

I would like to create domain names for 3 websites. For each of the 3 websites I have written down 20-30 ideas.

Is there a website I can go to to see if the .com domain for the ideas I have are available or taken? Manually entering 1 at a time takes a while.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to godaddy.com and click on Bulk Domain Name registration.

**edit** Here's the link:  http://www.godaddy.com/domains/searchbulk.aspx